# How to decide RFID tag antenna inductance?

Tags: antenna, rfid, pcb-antenna

I know how to calculate the antenna inductance of a given RFID tag antenna but how do I decide what value of antenna inductance is needed for the design?

Comment: Isn't **the antenna inductance of a given RFID tag** exactly the same as **value of antenna inductance is needed for the design** or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Andyaka Doesnt inductance change with antenna design? for example near vs far field, travelling wave or dish, etc? I would find it hard to beleive that these two have the same inductance: https://keonn.com/components-product/advantenna-p11/ and https://keonn.com/components-product/advantenna-p16/